# Not able to access Redis cache from aws sam application

Tags: aws-serverless

I am trying to access redis cache from aws sam application with nodejs as runtime.
The redis server was running and I am able to connect using terminal.
When sam application is trying to access the redis, its showing the below error message

```
error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
```

I tried to changing the bind option to 0.0.0.0 and protectedMode to no in redis config file `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf`, but still facing the same issue.

```
import redis, {RedisClient} from 'redis';

export default class LocalCache {
    private  client: RedisClient;
    constructor(host?: string, port?: number ) {
        this.client = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');
        this.client.on('connect', function() {
            console.info('Redis client connected');
        });
    }

    public close() {
        return this.client.quit();
    }

    public read(key: string): Promise<string | null> {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.get(key, (err, res) => {
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(res);
            });
        });
    }

    public write(key: string, value: string, time?: number | string, 
           expiryMode?: 'ex' | 'px'): Promise<string|null> {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            if (time) {
                expiryMode = expiryMode || 'ex';
                this.client.set(key, value, expiryMode, 30)
                resolve('success');
            }
            this.client.set(key, value);
            resolve('success');
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the SAM application in local, I would expect that the sam application should be able to access the local redis and allows me to do get and set values in cache.

Comment: Did you restart redis after making the change? And please keep the security risks of exposing redis using `protectedMode` no in mind.